# ReactJS: Pass parameter from rails to react router to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-on-rails

I am trying to pass a value from the render function to the component:

```
= react_component('App', props: {test: 'abc'}, prerender: false)
```

Routes.jsx

```
<Route path="/" component={App} >
```

App.jsx (component)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header test={this.props.test}>
      </Header>
      {this.props.children}
      <Footer />
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = { test: PropTypes.string };
```

There does not seem to be a coherent answer to this complete flow.

I have tried the following:

```
<Route path="/" component={() => (<App myProp="value" />)}/>
```

But this still does not answer the question of picking up the value provided by the initial render call(react_component)

Comment: Use `render` instead

Comment: Which version of React Router are you using?

Comment: @Dez I am using react-router 3.0.5

Comment: @SterlingArcher could you provide an end to end answer using render? That would greatly help

Comment: @AlexJose sure, here's an example of how I use it with props https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/src/index.jsx

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks for the example, but I am not sure if that answers my question. I am looking on how I can pass a parameter from the "view" to  the "react router" to the "component".

Answer (score 1):

> Looking for an end to end answer on how to pass a parameter from the
>   "view" to the "react router" to the "component"

We will start from the view:

```
<%= react_component('MyRoute', {test: 123}, prerender: false) %>
```

Now we will create a component that holds our `route`:

```
class MyRoute extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" render={() => <App test={this.props.test} />} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, we passed the `test` prop from the `Route` component to the `App` component. Now we can use the `test` prop in the `App` component:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>{this.props.test}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to throw an error at the first step itself, while calling the component from the view. `ArgumentError(wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)`

Comment: try removing `prerender: false`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path="/" render={attr => <App {...attr} test="abc" />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Router v3 you would do something like this

Wrap your App component under withRouter like this

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header test={this.props.test}>
      </Header>
      {
        this.props.children &&
        React.clone(this.props.children, {...this.props} )}
      <Footer />
    );
  }
}
App.propTypes = { test: PropTypes.string };
export const APP = withRouter(App);
```

And construct your routes like this...

```
<Route path="/" component={APP}>
  <Route path="/lobby" component={Lobby} />
  <Route path="/map" component={GameMap} />
  ...
</Route>
```

So your child routes will be rendered inside the APP children property an the props will be passed down to them.

Hope this helps!